# Error: "no match for 'operator*'

Tags: operator-overloading, overloading, operator-keyword, operand

I'm writing a calculator program for complex numbers and I am getting an error during compiling that says

```
In member function 'Complex Complex::operator*(const Complex&)': 

error: no match for 'operator*' (operand types are 'int' and 'const Imaginary')

iparts = (real * rhs.imagine) + (imagine * rhs.real);

               ^
```

What does this mean?

Comment: I politely suggest that you include the programming language and development environment that you're using. From the syntax, I'll guess that this is C++. For best results, you should also tag your question with the programming language.

Comment: Also, if you do not get an answer soon, please check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on improving your question.

Comment: It means that the operation given in the error message has not been defined.